# .csv import XAML report tool

Tags: xaml, csv

First off let me excuse me for my lack of coding knowledge, i'm totally new to this.

I work in a laboratory and one of the machines can produce a report based upon a XAML file. In order to get the correct variables into the machine we use a .csv file.

Can anybody help me how to set up the import of the CSV values into XAML report.

I already googled this question but my knowledge of coding is far to limited to compile a decent code.

Example of .csvfile

```
Aspirate offset;Dispense offset;Volume A;Volume B;Number;Solvent
3;1;100;900;12;DMSO
4;2;200;800;;
5;3;300;700;;
6;4;400;600;;
7;5;500;500;;
8;6;600;400;;
9;7;700;300;;
46;8;800;200;;
47;9;900;100;;
```

The number of lines below the header is variable.

XAMl code i have so far:

```
 <UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="450">
<Grid  Margin="10">
        <StackPanel>
                <Viewbox Width="200" Margin="-370,10,0,0" >
                <Canvas Width="427.069" Height="72.588">
                    <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="25" Margin="-200,5,0,0">Test item:    ~Testitem~</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="25" Margin="-200,40,0,0">Project:        ~Project~</TextBlock>       
                </Canvas>
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Width="200" Margin="0,-70,0,0" >
            </Viewbox>
            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0,30,0,20" FontFamily="Arial"><Underline>Work-solultions report</Underline></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="12" Margin="20,15,0,0">User:               ~CurrentUserInput~</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="12" Margin="20,5,0,0">Created on:     ~CurrentTime~ ~CurrentDate~</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="12" Margin="20,5,0,0">System:            TEST </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="12" Margin="20,5,0,0"></TextBlock>            
            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="12" Margin="20,5,0,0">Work-solutions created according tot he schedule below</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="12" Margin="20,5,0,0"></TextBlock>    
<ListView x:Name="W_aanmaak" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="620">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Aspirate offset      "/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Dispense offset      "/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Pipet volume [µL]      "/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="solvent volume [µL]      "/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Number of W's      "/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Solvent      "/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="12" Margin="550,220,0,0">Completed by:________________________</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock xml:space="preserve" FontSize="12" Margin="550,5,0,0">Checked By:___________________________</TextBlock>

</StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Info: the text between the ~ ~ are system variables (not imported by a .csv file).

when selecting the xaml file for the report, the machine prompts for a Folder and not for a specific file. Therefore i conclude that the machine is capable of running the code behind. There is no specific information about the report tool from the machine vendor.

Thanks is advance!

Comment: XAML is just a *markup language*, mostly used for Windows-based applications. We need more info (type of machine, XAML report layout, ...) before we can help. It's like saying: this csv file has to be placed into Word, without giving us the template for the layout or info on how the machine does the processing.

Comment: Edited with extra information